# How can I execute a third party C programm using nginx fast-cgi for web server?

Tags: c, nginx, server, fastcgi, nginx-config

I and a project team are trying to make our server use a C algorithm in background of our hosted website. Our server as bitnami nginx already installed but i can't find any information on the net about nginx fast cgi and C programms. If you can provide any help, I would be grateful.

We tried looking for informations but all we have found is that nginx does not automatically spawn fast-cgi process.

Comment: Hm, nginx documentation comes with information on fastcgi, and even [a couple examples](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/). So, since I assume you looked in that intuitive location for documentation, what didn't work, or what remained unclear. Were you able to implement your fastcgi server, or weren't you? At this point it's not clear what you're wondering about.

Comment: (also, honestly, C is the last language I'd implement a CGI application in, considering how incredibly annoying and error-prone, and thus security vulnerable, C is when it comes to handling string data… but that's your choice.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer, thing is we were requiered to use C in a CGI application, also i looked at the exemple on the nginx doc, and it's a php only example, so i assumed it was different for C-like languages

Comment: you seem to have not understood what FastCGI is, then! If you want to use your C code with a web server that generates FastCGI requests, it's your job to implement a FastCGI server. FastCGI and CGI are not quite the same thing. CGI is positively dead – nginx doesn't support CGI at all (by design; spawning CGI processes really doesn't fit into nginx' design paradigm), only FastCGI.

Answer (score 1):

NGINX has support for 3rd party modules.

There are two ways.

1. Since NGINX is written in C, you can write your C Algorithms inside an NGINX location module handler function.
2. You may need to write an Upstream module and a location module that can redirect HTTP requests coming from clients for any configured location to a backend server where you can write your C algorithm.

Please check this article https://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html

And if you want to use FCGI protocol, You should build NGINX source code with FCGI module and then you have to write an FCGI server in C and there you can implement C Algorithms

Comment: Nice! Honest question: That article is 16 years old, though, back when nginx was version 0.5. Does it still apply to nginx > 1.20?

Comment: yes, there are no changes in the module architecture, all we need to do is set some handler functions to register the module handler for a location, handle a request, initialize configurable fields with default values, to merge configurable values from configuration file, etc

Answer (score 1):

Did you already find [this fastcgiexample article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/) on [www.nginx.com](http://www.nginx.com)?

It says the following about spawning:

> Unlike Apache or Lighttpd, NGINX does not automatically spawn FCGI
> processes. You must start them separately.

I have used libfcgi.so with lighttpd. Example program that uses libfcgi.so here: [chapter C/C++ FastCGI on lighttpd named socket](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Mod_fastcgi).

With NGINX you may need to use TCP sockets (FCGX_OpenSocket) instead of UNIX domain sockets.